# Jetty Websocket Authentication

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I play the Jetty Websocket use example here :

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples (i use native-jetty-websocket-example)

I just move from websocketpp (C++) to Java Jetty Websocket and i just wonder **is there any way for me to authen the connection before the connection move to the onWebSocketConnect event** ?

Back in websocketpp i'll authenticate the connection via url (eg: ws://xxx/?key=123) when i will accept the connection or not. I can drop the connection before it "upgrade", and the client will result in connect failed

In Java i don't known how to do that, when the event come to onWebSocketConnect then the connection is etablished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up Security Constraints for that path and configure the Jetty authentication mechanisms, see details of how to do that here https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-security.

You could also use the `JettyWebSocketCreator` to do some checks on the HTTP Request just before the connection upgrades to WebSocket. Instead of this line https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/564c40b56413905cadeb500ade40d53e578ea990/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java#L55

You can do something like:

```java
wsContainer.addMapping("/events/*", (req, resp) ->
{
    if (!Objects.equals(req.getParameterMap().get("key"), "123"))
    {
        resp.sendError(...);
        return null;
    }

    return new EventSocket();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i'm locking for. However there are 1 thing is : when resp.sendError(...); the connection is closed or not ? i want force disconnect the connection

Comment: No it won't force disconnect the connection, it will send an HTTP error response and the connection will not be upgraded to WebSocket. You can use `Connection: close` header to close it after the response is sent. I think you could instead use `sendError(-1, "message")` to abort the channel and there will be no response.